# How can I automatically register all my fluent validators with Unity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container, fluentvalidation

Right now I've got my validators hooked up and building in my app, but every time we add a new validator we need to manually go into our Unity configuration and register the type. I'd like to do this automatically, much like [this blog post describes doing with StructureMap](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/02/22/using-fluentvalidation-with-an-ioc-container/), only for Unity instead.

Right now I've got something like this:

```
    // in global.asax.cs
    protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // some irrelevant registrations (area registrations, route config, etc)

        var container = new UnityContainer();
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(container);
        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(c => c.ValidatorFactory = new UnityValidatorFactory(container));
    }

public class UnityValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public UnityValidatorFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        if (container.IsRegistered(validatorType))
        {
            return container.Resolve(validatorType) as IValidator;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromAssemblies(
                Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (UnityConfig)),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, WithName.Default);

        RegisterValidators(container);

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static void RegisterValidators(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<IValidator<MyFirstViewModel>, MyFirstViewModelValidator>();           
        container.RegisterType<IValidator<MySecondViewModel>, MySecondViewModelValidator>();                                   
    }
 }
```

What I have is working, but I have to keep adding registrations to RegisterValidators() every time a new validator is created. Is there a way I can set this up to automatically detect and register all validators?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This turned out to be pretty easy once I figured out what I was doing, which maybe explains why Googling for the answer was yielding no results. I rewrote RegisterValidators as follows:

```
private static void RegisterValidators(IUnityContainer container)
{
        var validators = AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssemblyContaining<OneOfMyValidators>();
        validators.ForEach(validator => container.RegisterType(validator.InterfaceType, validator.ValidatorType));
}
```

Comment: Did you ever come across a different approach so that you didn't have to know about any of the validators? I tried a bunch of stuff too and this is the only one I could get working, but having to name a validator has a funny smell to it.

Comment: No, that's a problem I've had with all sorts of reflection-based code where I'm looking for a particular assembly. `

Comment: You don't have to specify the type of a validator. You can specify any type, just as long as it's in the same assembly as your validators.

Answer (score 1):

You can let FV setup do the job for you, [please refer to 1st comment here for more details from the contributers](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/410)

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
        {
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>...);
            services.AddMvc()
                    .AddFluentValidation( o =>
                    {
                        o.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
                    } );
```

Comment: The original question was for ASP.NET MVC, not ASP.NET Core MVC. This answer is for ASP.NET Core MVC.